# Visio 2010 - saving a SharePoint Workflow

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2010, workflow, sharepoint-workflow, visio-2010

I want to be able to save a SharePoint Workflow in Microsoft Visio Premium 2010. When I try to save a workflow I have created in Visio, the vwi filetype is not available from the pick list. What do I need to do to make this available?

Answer (score 0):

To answer my own question, saving as a Visio Workflow Interchange (vwi) is not available as a save as option. A vwi file can only be generated in Visio by choosing Export.[See this screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EYqVy.png)